Login to GitHub - Server is unreachable
I´ve been working on a project for the past couple of days in pycharm and suddenly when trying to commit the connection failed and the push was getting rejected. Ive now reset all files, set up a new repository but now am even unable to clone my project from VCS as the clone fails every time. I have also now removed the Git Account connection and tried to set up a new one but every time I try via login I get the error message "We were unable to authorize you in GitHub. Sorry for inconvenience, please try again later." or when trying to use a GitHub token get the message "server is unreachable".
At this point I am really desperate and open for any help!
Thanks!!
connecting pycharm to GitHub via token and login fails: "We were unable to authorize you in GitHub. Sorry for inconvenience, please try again later." and "server is unreachable", pushing and committing to repository. Also I have tried to change my http proxy to "no proxy".
